# How can I round a date object to the end of the month in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the date `2010-11-24` and this date expires in 3 years. The expiry date needs to be calculated to the end of the month for that month. In this case, November.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2010-11-24', INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
```

This returns `2013-11-24`. What I need is for it to return `2013-11-30`.

Is this possible to do in an MySQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [LAST_DAY function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day):

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD('2010-11-24', INTERVAL 3 YEAR))
```

Comment: That was a lot easier than I was assuming it'd be... Cheers